# How can I remove `artifactory_name` from JFrog's Artifactory cloud url

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control, jfrog-container-registry

I have created an on-cloud JFrog account. As per my requirement, I have to remove artifactory_name from jfrog url. Currently, I have

```
https://example.jfrog.io/example/webapp/#/home
```

I want

```
https://example.jfrog.io/webapp/#/home
```

How could I remove second `example` from above URL

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this functionality is not supported by JFrog's cloud offering.

Comment: 1 more query please

If user has jfrog account with artifactory(example) name he can do search like below i.e
 curl -u user_name:Password -X POST http://example.jfrog.io/example/api/search/aql -T listimage.aql

but if the account doesn't has artifactory name for someone, how can he do something like above

Comment: Are you asking if AQL query can be run against api with no artifactory context? On non cloud - yes. This should be possible as you wrote. Assuming you have the Pro license installed and Artifactory configured properly with the removal of the context.