# How can I remove `artifactory_name` from JFrog's Artifactory on-premises url

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control, jfrog-container-registry

I have created an on-premises JFrog account. As per my requirement, I have to remove artifactory_name from jfrog url. Currently, I have 
https://example.jfrog.io/example/webapp/#/home
I want
https://example.jfrog.io/webapp/#/home

[image]

On saving Reverse proxy gives below error

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:430)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)



Nov 25, 2019 7:46:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor service
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:430)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove \`artifactory\_name\` from JFrog's Artifactory cloud url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968751/how-can-i-remove-artifactory-name-from-jfrogs-artifactory-cloud-url)

Comment: Its running on -premises not in cloud ….can any one suggest how can I do

Comment: Are you following the instructions in the wiki? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy

Comment: Please provide more input. I was trying to reproduce your issue with no success - the "Public Context Path" field is disabled in the UI.

Comment: @292kumargaurav007 this seems word to word duplicate of the previous question you asked. What is your scenario, cloud or on-prem? Please leave only one question with the real problem you have.